# Creating console type text animation dynamically

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am creating a webapp in ColdFusion that will execute a bash script on the server.  What I want to do is output either the BASH output itself within a webpage dynamically (realtime), or output my own status text based on checking the status of the job.  For instance, if I am running one bash script and it completes successfully, I want to put that on the website, but output like this:

```
Starting test.sh....COMPLETE.
```

I want it to pause at the .... and wait there for me to check the output (or log file) and then write COMPLETE or FAILED, depending on what the log tells me.  Is there a way to do this live?  I apologize if this isn't clear.

Comment: `cfflush` will get you started.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would load up a page completely. The page would then have then have background AJAX pull the status on a regular basis. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polling+jquery

Comment: @James,  I am new to the advanced techniques of ColdFusion and have researched and found ways to do something similar in PHP but nothing in ColdFusion.  I will start researching cfflush, just haven't found specific examples for something close to what I am trying to accomplish.  Any resources you can point me to will be helpful.  Thanks so much.

Comment: If you have a PHP example of what you have done, that would be useful. Also you need to show the ColdFusion code you have tried

Comment: @James, I am not coding in php I meant I found in my research approaches people took using php.  I haven't coded anything yet in ColdFusion.  Was looking for guidance on where to look and how to begin.  I will start researching cfflush and see where that takes me.  Any other guidance is appreciated.  Thanks to ask who have weighed in so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting Java to do this kind of thing:

```
<cfscript>
    p = createObject("java", "java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime().exec("/tmp/foo.sh");
    reader = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedReader").init(createObject("java", "java.io.InputStreamReader").init(p.getInputStream()));

    line = reader.readLine();

    while (not isNull(line))
    {
        writeOutput(line);
        writeOutput("<br />");
        getPageContext().getOut().flush();
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    writeOutput("<hr />");
    writeOutput("done!");
</cfscript>
```

Where the shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "one"
sleep 1
echo -e "two"
sleep 1
echo -e "three"
sleep 1
echo -e "four"
sleep 1
echo -e "five"
```